# I'm unable to figure out what test cases am I failing here

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the maximum occurring character in a string: a-z. It is 26 characters long i.e. 26 different types.

Even though the output is correct, I'm still failing. What am I doing wrong?

**These are the conditions:**

Note: If there are more than one type of equal maximum then the type with lesser ASCII value will be considered.

**Input Format**
The first line of input consists of number of test cases, T.

The second line of each test case consists of a string representing the type of each individual characters.

**Constraints**

1<= T <=10

1<= |string| <=100000

**Output Format**

For each test case, print the required output in a separate line.

**Sample TestCase 1**

**Input**

2

gqtrawq

fnaxtyyzz

**Output**

q

y

**Explanation**

**Test Case 1:** There are 2 q occurring the max while the rest all are present alone.

**Test Case 2:** There are 2 y and 2 z types. Since the maximum value is same, the type with lesser Ascii value is considered as output. Therfore, y is the correct type.

```
def testcase(str1):

  ASCII_SIZE = 256

  ctr = [0] * ASCII_SIZE

  max = -1

  ch = ''

  for i in str1:

    ctr[ord(i)]+=1;


  for i in str1:

    if max < ctr[ord(i)]:

      max = ctr[ord(i)]

      ch = i

  return ch

print(testcase("gqtrawq"))

print(testcase("fnaxtyyzz"))
```

**I'm passing the output i.e. I'm getting the correct output but failing the test cases.**

Comment: In case of ties, you are not necessarily returning the char with lowest ordinal value but the one that appears first in the original string. For `fnaxtyyzz` those just happen to be the same.

Comment: I need to return the character with the highest count. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Note the note:

> Note: If there are more than one type of equal maximum then the type with lesser ASCII value will be considered.

But with your code, you return the character with highest count *that appears first in the string*. In case of ties, take the character itself into account in the comparison:

```
for i in str1:
  if max < ctr[ord(i)] or max == ctr[ord(i)] and i < ch:
    max = ctr[ord(i)]
    ch = i
```

Or shorter (but not necessarily clearer) comparing tuples of `(count, char)`:

```
  if (max, i) < (ctr[ord(i)], ch):
```

(Note that this is comparing `(old_cnt, new_char) < (new_cnt, old_chr)`!)

Alternatively, you could also iterate the characters in the string in sorted order:

```
for i in sorted(str1):
  if max < ctr[ord(i)]:
    ...
```

Having said that, you could simplify/improve your code by counting the characters directly instead of their `ord` (using a `dict` instead of `list`), and using the `max` function with an appropriate `key` function to get the most common character.

```
def testcase(str1):
    ctr = {c: 0 for c in str1}
    for c in str1:
        ctr[c] += 1
    return max(sorted(set(str1)), key=ctr.get)
```

You *could* also use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and `most_common`, but where's the fun in that?

Comment: Hi Tobias, can you tell me how can I make it a multiline input? 

"Input Format: The first line of input consists of number of test cases, T.
The second line of each test case consists of a string representing the type of each individual characters."

Comment: @NaliniPanwar Hm, I could, but I won't, because then there's nothing left for you to do. Hint: There is no "multiline input" in Python, just `input()`, which reads a single line, which you can then split, or convert to integers, or something. So just use multiple single-line inputs.

Comment: Thank you. I did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

What should be the output for this - print(testcase("fanaxtyfzyz"))?

IMO the output should be 'a' but your program writes 'f'.
The reason is you are iterating through the characters of the input string,

```
for i in str1: #Iterating through the values 'f','a','n','a','x','t',...
               #first count of 'f' is considered. 
               #count of 'f' occurs first, count of 'a' not considered.
if max < ctr[ord(i)]: 

  max = ctr[ord(i)]

  ch = i
```

Instead, you should iterate through the values of ctr. Or sort the input string and do the same.